# Function Import into VS 2012 - some datatypes are changed to Nullable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that I added to my MVC3 project using the function import in VS 2012.  The stored procedure grabs the ID which is the PK for the table, some varchars and a datetime field.  The varchars are converted the strings, as they should.  However, the Id is changed to a nullable int and the Datetime field is changed to a nullable Datetime.  Neither the table nor the viewmodel in the app are nullable, only the function/stored procedure show as nullable.  This of course causes a problem when I try to put the data into the view model from the stored procedure, I get "Can't implicitly convert..." errors trying to go from nullable to non.

I know I can manually change the data types in the function import, in the model browser, but if I ever update my EDMX model, it changes them back.  Not sure what (if any) code to post, so let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you're not going to be able to convince Entity Framework that those fields aren't null-able. Instead, you have to modify your code that maps the result to the ViewModel:

```
viewModel.Id = result.Id;
```

Would become:

```
viewModel.Id = result.Id.Value;
```

And as long as you are absolutely positive that the field will never be null, you won't have to worry about null references.